# Facebook Authentication scenario with Appium

Tags: authentication, automated-tests, appium, facebook-ui

I am testing in Appium a native mobile app. In the facebook login scenario, i have noticed that the UI of the authentication popup changes randomly and that causes tests to fail. Any idea how to control this? I mean, can i create two verifyat() methods and then implement an if condition which will continue to verify the alternative UI that comes from FB if the first one fails? Thanks

Comment: Facebook login - Once you login then it won't prompt login page and goes directly to authentication page. So first validate the Authentication "OK" button then if fails used Login page.

Comment: Let me be more clear. I am referring to the facebook login popup that comes up after I click the fb button from my native app. That popup sometimes comes with a different UI and my tests fail as a matter of fact. Is there any solution that I can implement? Lets say, if it doesn't recognise the first UI, to move on to verify the second one. Has anyone come up with this issue before???